# Micronaut: Loggers in certain packages are not appearing in AWS lambda and in local

Tags: gradle, logging, micronaut

The `Micronaut` version I am using is `1.3.4` and `gradle` dependency for logging is `runtimeOnly "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.3.0-alpha5"`.

I have specified the packages and their log levels in `logback.xml`.
I am facing the following issues with loggers:

- It only works when all packages specified in the project structure have the word ***service*** in them. So, the below configuration works perfectly.

  ```
  <configuration>
     <appender name="STDOUT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type 
        ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder 
        by default -->
      <encoder>
       <pattern>%cyan(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}) %gray([%thread])
           %highlight(%-5level) %magenta(%logger{36}) - %msg%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
   </appender>
     <logger name="io.micronaut.https.client" level="TRACE"/>
     <root level="info">
         <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
     </root>
     <logger name="com.abc.eng.service.api" level="info">
         <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
     </logger>
     <logger name="com.abc.eng.service" level="info">
         <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
     </logger> 
  </configuration>
  ```
- However, if there are packages excluding `service` from their name, none of the loggers from any of the packages show up in my local or in `CloudWatch` logs. i.e.,

  ```
  <configuration>
     <appender>
           ......
     </appender>
     <logger name="io.micronaut.https.client" level="TRACE"/>
     <root level="info">
       <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
     </root>
     <logger name="com.abc.eng" level="info">
       <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
     </logger>
     <logger name="com.abc.eng.service.api" level="info">
       <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
     </logger>
     <logger name="com.abc.eng.service" level="info">
       <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
     </logger>  
  </configuration>
  ```

As package `com.abc.eng` doesn't have ***service*** as a part of the package name, none of the loggers appear from any of the packages specified (not even loggers from the ***service*** named packages like `com.abc.eng.service.api` or `com.abc.eng.service`).

Is this a version issue since loggers in microservices with older `Micronaut` versions - `1.1.1` work perfectly? Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: We ship Micronaut 1.3.4 with a dependency on `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3` by default.  If you use that version, does your logging work as expected?

Comment: I tried with this version `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3` but even this is not working as expected

Comment: "It only works when all packages specified in the project structure have the word service in them. " - I have not been able to reproduce that.

Comment: Can you show the definition of your `"STDOUT"` appender?

Comment: This is the appender in my `logback.xml` 
  `<appender name="STDOUT"
  class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder 
   by default -->
  <encoder>
   <pattern>%cyan(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}) %gray([%thread])
    %highlight(%-5level) %magenta(%logger{36}) - %msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
 </appender`

Comment: The appender that you have now added to the question does not have a name but the one you added to the comment does.  Which of those is consistent with your application code?

Comment: With the name is the consistent one. I have edited my question